# angular js not working in contentplace holder/ master page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

with out master page angular js working fine. but while adding master page angular.js functions not working properly.how to write function and ids according to content place. what to change in function?

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
     <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.qty =10;
        $scope.unitprice =10;
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <div ng-app>
<table ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<tr>
  <td>
    <lable> Qty : </lable>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" runat="server" ID="txtQty" ng-model="qty" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <lable> Unit Price : </lable>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" runat="server" ID="txtUnitPrice" ng-model="unitprice" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <lable>Total Price :</lable>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" runat="server" ID="txttotalprice" ng-model="totalprice" ng-bind="{{totalprice= qty*unitprice }}" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: where is you `ng-app` attribute or `angular.bootstrap`?

Comment: tried adding with ngapp.but still not working

Comment: thanks its working..<div ng-app="myApp">

Answer (score 0):

Switch to angular-material md-content and remove all asp tags. Create a scripts directory with an app.js file and out your angluar js code in it. Then reference in your view. Mixing ASP and Angular will not end well. [Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdContent)

Your app.js should look like:

```
angular.module('opcaApp', ['ngMaterial'])
//your controller code.
```

Then in an outer div or inside a md-content directive interact with your controller code:

```
<md-content>
 <div ng-controller="<your controller>">

 </div>
</md-content>
```